# write a query that return that return supplementary relationship between two nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j db which have this form

```
(:FBuser)-[:Published]->(:Post)<-[:Tagged_in]-(:Friend)<-[:Tagged_together]->(:Friend)
```

A Post `(:Node)` could have two or more Nodes `(:Friend)` connected with it.

I want to write a query that returns this schema

```
(:FBuser)-[:Friend]->(n:Friend)-[:Tagged_in]->(:Post)<-[:Tagged_in]-(m:Friend)<-[:Tagged_together]->(n)
```

where for `(:Post)` I need all the post for that specific `(n:Friend)`. The problem is that not all the `(:Post)` has connected with another `(m:Friend)` so, only for some nodes I have  `(n:Friend)<-[:Tagged_together]->(m:Friend)`

I write this code but obviously returns just all the nodes `(:Post)` for a specific node `(:Friend)` and supplementary `(:Friend)` connected with it

```
MATCH t=(:fbUser)-[:FRIEND]-(w)-[:TAGGED_IN]-(p)
MATCH s=(:Friend)-[:TAGGED_IN]-(q)
WHERE  
     w.name=~ '(?i).*edoardo.*' AND
     q.timestamp=p.timestamp AND
     w.nodeDegree>=0 
RETURN t,s
```

How can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try optional match. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/

I used a coalesce statement so that the timestamp filter will still return records if q is null.

```
MATCH t=(:fbUser)-[:FRIEND]-(w)-[:TAGGED_IN]-(p)
OPTIONAL MATCH s=(:Friend)-[:TAGGED_IN]-(q)
WHERE  
     w.name=~ '(?i).*edoardo.*' AND
     coalesce(q.timestamp, p.timestamp)=p.timestamp AND
     w.nodeDegree>=0 
RETURN t,s
```